# Software that supports S3 API from HTML Forms?

Tags: amazon-s3, riak-cs, walrus

I've tried Riak CS and Walrus, and read a few other's documentation pages but can't tell whether they would support this or not.

What I have is an application that uses S3 policies to allow the client to upload and download directly from their browser. I'm looking for a way to replace S3 (for some customers, who would prefer their data not in Amazon's cloud), without having to maintain two different branches of code everywhere I currently talk to S3.

Example of what I do now:
https://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434

Help would be greatly appreciated, I'm stumped!

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are trying to accomplish? If you are already using HTTP Post to Amazon S3, and you want to "replace S3 for some customers", are you saying that you want a website to support the S3 upload method so you can talk to S3 and "not S3" in the same way?

Comment: I want something that sits on hardware I'm in control of that has an API that's compatible with S3. Riak CS claims to be compatible but I can't get it to accept files from HTML forms.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called "POST OBJECT". Just check document of S3 compatible implements to see support status.

For example, Walrus claims that it supports POST OBJECT. https://github.com/eucalyptus/eucalyptus/wiki/Walrus-S3-API

On the other hand, Riak CS does not support POST OBJECT http://docs.basho.com/riakcs/latest/references/apis/storage/s3/

Ps.: Many S3 implements claims that they are compatible with AWS S3. In fact, it is not ture. If you want fully compatibility, try google cloudian.